# Looping with string and characters

Tags: python, loops

Hey guys can someone help me with with something. i want to build a loop where the user input should only contain 1 character of "@" and continue looping until the user's input contain only one @ in their mail can some help building this?
this is my last approach i tried so many methods which i deleted but this is the last one...

```
mail = input("enter email address: ")
count = {}

for character in mail:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] = count[character] + 1
x = int(count['@'])
while x != 1:
    print("Invalid mail !! (error in '@')")
    mail = input("Enter valid mail: ")
    print(count)
```

Comment: Please add the script you've written so far.

Comment: What issues are you having with this code?

Comment: Your while loop doesn't reevaluate new input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in `python` for counting the characters.
Using the `count` function, your code could be reduced to the following:

```
while True:
    mail = input("enter email address: ")
    if mail.count('@') != 1:
        print("Invalid mail !! (error in '@')")
    else:
        break
```

and the result:

```
>>> python test.py
enter email address: myemail
Invalid mail !! (error in '@')

enter email address: myemail@provider@com
Invalid mail !! (error in '@')

enter email address: myemail@provider.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use infinte loop and break with if condition. You can do this:

```
while True:
    mail = input("enter email address: ")
    count = {}

    for character in mail:
        count.setdefault(character, 0)
        count[character] = count[character] + 1
    x = int(count['@'])

    if not x == 1:
        print("Invalid mail !! (error in '@')")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Here I used infinite loop and if condition to ask user again and again for new email and break it after it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I used `count` variable instead of `dictionary` .

```
count = 0
mail = input('enter email address: ')

while True:
    for character in mail:
        if character == '@':
            count += 1

    if count != 1:
        count = 0
        print('Invalid mail !! (error in \'@\')')
        mail = input('Enter valid mail: ')
    else:
        break
```